# how to add a div and apply a style to it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

the code is like this:

```
    <div id="comments">
     <h2>comments list</h2>
    <div class="clear-block">....</div>
   <div class="clear-block">....</div>
    <div class="clear-block">....</div>
  <div class="indented">....</div> // this div is indented.
  <div class="box"...</div>
  </div>
```

now, i want to use jquery to add a border to the

```
 <h2>......</div>
```

part.maybe i shoule add a div label first  before the h2 label, then the close label

```
       </div>
```

before

```
<div class="box">   .
```

then using a style

```
        border:1px...
```

but i don't how to do it. thank you.

the border effect like this http://phplist.xxmn.com/1.jpg

Comment: Please clarify what you're looking for. This question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clear-block,.indented,.box').css('border', '1px solid black');
```

Comment: but there is no border to h2, and the indented div.

Comment: .. then simply change the selector to `$('.clear-block,.box').css('border', '1px solid black');`   If later you want to specifically exclude all `<h2>` for some reason, you can always add `.not()` to your selector:  `$('.clear-block,.indented,.box').not('h2').css('border', '1px solid black')`